# Checking if workspace is properly overlayed by the setup script

Tags: ros, catkin.workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace

The last step is to make sure that workspace is properly overlayed by the setup script.
For that, I entered this:

```
$ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

As I have ROS Indigo, so I was expecting this:

```
/home/username/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share
```

But I am getting this:

```
/home/username/catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks
```

What does this additional `:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks` mean and why does this appear? Is this some problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255618/checking-if-workspace-is-properly-overlayed-by-the-setup-script/) by [SarSam](https://answers.ros.org/users/26371/sarsam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2017-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, this is expected.

`/opt/ros/indigo/stacks` is added for backwards-compatibility reasons: in earlier versions of ROS, that is where all content of packages was placed (distributed in stacks, hence the name). As there could still be some old packages that depend on artefacts to be located there, the directory is still added to the package search path.

Note that even though the directory is added to the search path, whether it actually exits on your FS depends on whether you have installed any package that places artefacts there.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2017-02-28**:
Note that this disappears with kinetic...

**Comment by [atha](https://answers.ros.org/users/31615/atha/) on 2017-08-18**:
I have ROS Kinetic and i have a similar problem. After: `$ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`, im getting nothing(no path) in return. sorry, newbie here!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-18**:
A 'similar problem', or exactly the same? If similar, please search to see whether there is already a post dealing with yours, otherwise post a new question.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-08-18**:
Note that `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` will only be set after you have run `source /path/to/your/setup.bash`, where appropriate `setup.bash` may be found in the `devel` directory in your workspace, and in `/opt/ros/kinetic`.

**Comment by [atha](https://answers.ros.org/users/31615/atha/) on 2017-08-18**:
thanks a lot, i posted a new question to specify the problem